# Why response time with postgres is 15x higher than with sqlite?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Simple get request (django + django-rest-framework) with sqlite3 database takes 2ms.
Using postgres, response time extends to over 30ms. Why is that, how to make postgres faster?

Settings with sqlite:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

[image]
Settings with postgres:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'drf-test',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

[image]

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Product")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Products")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class ProductListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductModelSerializer
```

```
class ProductModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: You don't even show us the query, let alone `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Answer (score 0):

That difference is practically negligible.

Postgres is running a server essentially, so there could be I/O difference in timing. SQLite is file based, and you probably have a really small SQLite file/not many rows in your tables. Because of this, sqlite parsing will be very fast. But don't use SQLite in production; in this case, once the file starts growing, it'll not only consume more memory but also take much longer to parse through and your server response time will be much longer.